# Generate inside always_comb block in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I know you can not have a `generate` inside an `always_comb` block in SystemVerilog, but I want to do something similar to what I show below and I do not know how I could do it.

```
genvar i, j;
generate
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
    always_comb begin 
        unique case (STATE) 
            0: begin
               ...
               for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                   var[j*8+2*i+1:j*8+2*i] = 2'b11;
            end
            ...
        endcase

    end
end
endgenerate
```

Right now it gives me the following compilation error : `Unknown range in part select` 
Any help would be apreciatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `var` is a keyword in verilog, it cannot be used as a variable.
2. `genvar j` cannot be modified inside an always block.
3. *partselect* in system verilog must at least have a constant width.
4. you missed `endgenerate`

so, you need to

1. rename `var` to something else
2. declare `j` as a non-genvar variable, i.e., `int`
3. your width is always `2`, so you can use the system verilog `+:` or `-:` range specifiers
4. you do not really need `generate..endgenerate` markers any longer in system verilog.

here is an example:

```
genvar i;
//generate
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin: loop
    always_comb begin 
        unique case (STATE) 
            0: begin
               //...
              for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                v[j*8+2*i +: 2] = 2'b11;
                   //v[j*8+2*i+1:j*8+2*i] = 2'b11;
            end
            //...
        endcase
    end
  end
//endgenerate
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot the endgenerate as this was just a short example I wrote to post the question. By using `:+` I could fix my problem : ). Thank you so much! (Also, I did not know `j` could not be modified)